# Struct and segmentation fault in c

Tags: c

I'm currently new to the struct and linked list. I'm trying to put the values of my array arr_dec[4] in a variable. My array is on a struct, and also in my init function. I think my problem is on the display function, in my if loop.

[EDIT] :
Hi, so I think I correctly changed my errors, but I still get a segmentation fault, and really I don't understand why I get it. If you could see what is wrong and how I can correct it it'll be great ! Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Plane_dec Element; 
    struct Plane_dec 
    {
        int array_dec[4]; 
        int nbr_var; 
        struct Plane_dec *head; 
        struct Plane_dec *next; 
    };

void init(int nbr_caract) //It's my initialisation function, i want to initialize my linked list.
    {
        Element *plane_dec = malloc(sizeof(plane_dec));
        Element *head = NULL;
        Element *next = NULL;
        plane_dec->var_num = 0;
        plane_dec->arr_dec[0] = 2; 
        plane_dec->arr_dec[1] = 5; 
        plane_dec->arr_dec[2] = 1; 
        plane_dec->arr_dec[3] = 3;  
return *head;
    }

void display (int nbr)
    {
        int i = 0, variable = 0;
        struct Plane var;
        struct Plane_dec *plane_dec;
 
        init(nbr_caract);
 
        for(i = 0; i <4; i++) 
        { 
            variable = plane_dec->arr_dec[i]; 
            printf("%d - ", variable);
        }
    }

int main()
{
    int nbr;
    prinft("Please select a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &nbr);
    display(nbr);
return 0;
}
```

My output is just : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: This code can't even compile, much less run to a seg fault. The slew of errors and warnings from this should be both heeded *and* included with your question.

Comment: Yes, i'll add it right now

Comment: The errors must be included as text, not as images.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] if you would like to get any help.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time writing in this forum. I don't understand how you want me to include the errors? And i'll change my program for a more minimalist one.

Comment: No need to be sorry. When you ask a question here, include a single block of code with all includes and a `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Among other problems that prevent compilation:
In `display`, you pass an uninitialized pointer *to a pointer* of `Plane_dec` (you declare a pointer and then pass its address) to `init` (which is stated to expect just a pointer!), and then within `init` you attempt to modify its fields.
If what you've been meaning to do is dynamically allocate a `Plane_dec`, then you need to actually do so: `init` needs to begin with a `*plane_dec = malloc(...)`, and you need to modify its declaration to accept a pointer *to a pointer* to `Plane_dec`, and not just a pointer to `Plane_dec`.
If, on the other hand, what you've been meaning to do is just modify a local variable declared within `display` and then discard it when `display` finishes its run, then you don't want `display`'s `plane_dec` to be a pointer (so remove the asterisk from the variable declaration).

Either way, the `arr_dec` you declare within `init` gets promptly discarded and doesn't have anything to do with the similarly-named field of the `plane_dec` variable, and `nbr_var` also doesn't do anything, as it is. (Also note that in `display` you attempt to access the `arr_dec` field of `Plane_dec`, but the field is named `array_dec`, not `arr_dec`.)

If this doesn't solve your problem, please make sure to provide more context about what you've actually been meaning to do, as well as post your error (textually, not as an image), and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): make sure to copy the code in question into a brand new file and test that it compiles, and provide the error details based on *that*. It is quite likely that if you do all of this, you'll figure out the answers on your own; and if you don't, we'll be able to help a lot more efficiently.

Comment: I need a linked list that contains int variables that I will use in the rest of my program. So I think the best way is to use pointers, because if no, I'm just going to lose my linked list, right?

Comment: I also thought if ```arr_dec``` and ```nbr_var``` were on my struct then it'll be initialized in my ```init``` function and not just be local variable who just disapear at the end of ```init```. How can I fix it please?

Comment: If you're going for a linked list then you almost certainly want dynamic allocation. If you're not familiar with the notion, please Google `malloc` and look into it. Just having a pointer does not guarantee the element it points at will exist. A pointer is like a note with an address on it; you need to ensure that the address actually leads somewhere for that note to hold that kind of meaning.

Comment: As for arr_dec: just like you wrote `plane_dec->head = NULL` and not just `Element head = NULL`, you need to access the actual *fields*, and not simply create local variables with a similar name. So, for instance, `plane_dec->arr_dec[0] = 2`. About `nbr_var`, it isn't part of the struct you posted in your question, but if it were, the same idea would apply: `plane_dec->nbr_var`.

Comment: I'll try to use a dynamic allocation for my linked list. I'm sorry but I don't really understand the difference between ```plane_dec->head = NULL``` and ```Element head = NULL```, it's not the same? Thank you very much, I think I get your example with ```plane_dec->arr_dec[0] = 2```.

Comment: You're welcome! And no, it's certainly not the same: `Element head` is a local variable, while `plane_dec->head` is a field of `plane_dec`. If you make a `struct test { int x; };`, then in your main you'll be able to do `int x = 5; struct test s; s.x = 17;`, and notice that `x==5` but `s.x==17`. `x` and `s.x` are *not* the same variable. I encourage you to run the things I just wrote and see this for yourself. Furthermore, I recommend you read more about structs and about variable scopes to make sure that you understand how it all works.

Comment: Your example is more understandable for me. I'll do what you have suggested, thank you for all your advices ;) !

Comment: You're welcome, @megumi01! I hope it works out.

Comment: I'll probably come back (just because I know I'll ask some help again)